# Meteor install with npm install -g meteor fail with 403 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, meteor, meteor-blaze

Installing meteor with the command "npm install -g meteor" as instructed on their official site, https://www.meteor.com/developers/install gives the following error.

```
os
　win 10 pro
node -v
　v14.15.1
npm -v
　6.14.8
```

it gave this error:

```
Downloading |░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░| 0%events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Response status was 403
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jefferson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteor\node_modules\node-downloader-helper\dist\index.js:1:7153)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:641:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:509:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
Emitted 'error' event on b instance at:
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jefferson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteor\node_modules\node-downloader-helper\dist\index.js:1:7284)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10) {
  status: 403,
  body: ''
}
+ meteor@2.2.0
added 46 packages from 25 contributors in 16.461s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately going through the same error. Tried installing it with Admin rights too but failed.

An alternative approach that I used to install it on Windows was using Chocolatey.

Steps are as follows

a) Open PowerShell as an admin

b) Run `Get-ExecutionPolicy`. If returning restricted, execute the following - `Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned` or `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process`

c) Run this command `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

d) Once installation is complete. Write `choco` to check if it is actually installed.

e) Execute the following command `choco install meteor`

Source for Chocolatey Install can be found [here](https://chocolatey.org/install).